# Observable constructor being passed variable and being used in call

Tags: angular, observable

I have a question about the code below. The observer being passed in is being used in the call. For example  observer.next("bla bla bla").

I don't understand how observer.next exist if I'm passing it in?

```
 import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable"

    // create observable
    const simpleObservable = new Observable((observer) => {

        // observable execution
        observer.next("bla bla bla")
        observer.complete()
    })

    // subscribe to the observable
    simpleObservable.subscribe()

    // dispose the observable
    simpleObservable.unsubscribe()
```

Comment: The RxJS documentation will help.

Comment: If you are really interested, you can read the source code [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.5.2/src/internal/Subscriber.ts#L8-L162) for a `Subscriber` class.  According to the [documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subscriber) "all Observers get converted to a Subscriber", and it is in this conversion that they pick up the methods of the Subscriber class, such as `next()`, `complete()`, `unsubscribe()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing it in. You're defining an anonymous [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) which takes the `observer` parameter. The callback function is called internally from `Observable` and it passes the `observer` parameter to your defined callback function.

Comment: The callback function was clear. It's the observer.next('bla bal bla"). How does observer have the function next?

Answer (score 0):

The object being passed to the callback function is not an `Observable` but a `Subscriber` and if you check the docs of [Subscriber](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscriber.js~Subscriber.html) it has a method `next(value: T): void`

Also note that `simpleObservable.unsubscribe()` is not valid as the Observable can't unsubscribe itself. Valid code would be below, even tho it is not necessary to unsubscribe if the `complete()` call is made.

```
const sub = simpleObservable.subscribe(e => console.log(e));
sub.unsubscribe();
```